# Why would subclassing NSFormatter prevent me from editing NSTextField's input?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, input, nstextfield, nsformatter

I'm trying to format two NSTextFields for SMPTE time codes, which have the format:
`HH:MM:SS:FF`.  However, when the user switches the SMPTE code to drop-frame, the delimiter between SS and FF needs to switch to a `;` (`HH:MM:SS;FF`).  To do this, I've subclassed NSFormatter, and have it mostly working except for one very stubborn problem.

The text field accepts input just fine, but if I highlight-replace, backspace, delete, or insert any new characters into the text field, I get an NSBeep and I can't switch focus away from the text field.  I can input new text if I delete the whole text field first, but not if I try to edit the existing input.  Here are my implemented methods/overrides:

```
- (NSString*)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj
{
    if ( ! [obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"00:00:00:00"];

    int length = (int)[[obj stringValue] length];
    int insertLocation = 9;

    if (length == 1)
    {
        [string replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, 1) withString:[obj stringValue]];
    }
    else
    {
        while (length > 1)
        {
            NSString *temp = [[obj stringValue] substringFromIndex:length-2];
            [string replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(insertLocation, 2) withString:temp];

            obj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[obj intValue]/100];
            length -= 2;
            insertLocation -= 3;
        }

        if (length == 1)
        {
            [string replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(insertLocation+1, 1) withString:[obj stringValue]];
        }
    }

    return string;
}

- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out __autoreleasing id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(out NSString *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    int valueResult;
    NSScanner *scanner;
    BOOL returnValue = NO;

    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: string];
    [scanner scanString:@":" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanString:@";" intoString:NULL];

    if ([scanner scanInt:&valueResult] && ([scanner isAtEnd])) {
        returnValue = YES;
        if (obj)
        {
            *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueResult];
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

At least at this point, I don't need to validate the input during editing, only when editing is finished.  I tried implementing `isPartialStringValid` and just returning `YES`, but that didn't seem to help either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just solved it by doing some more testing.  It appears as though why it was failing is because `getObjectValue` was receiving the string with the delimiters in them and was not correctly removing them.  I simply replaced the method with this:

```
- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(out __autoreleasing id *)obj forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(out NSString *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSString *newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];

    if (obj)
    {
        *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[newString intValue]];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Now it works perfectly.